# Ending a sentence with をさ

Tags: particle-を

> 現場に彼が現れてさ
> たぶん殺さなくていいモンをさ

My understanding of the sentence is akin to "He appeared at the place. Perhaps, it won't be necessary to kill him"

This is said by a character overseeing the events from afar about the appearance of a certain person.

However, what does をさ indicate?

After that the scene ends and it moves to some other conversation.

Answer (score 2):

You're overthinking it. ～さ～さ is a casual speaking style, it's like saying "you see" after every couple of words. "So Sam you see, took a shower you see, then headed out you see."

を is just an object marker here and the verb is omitted or might be said in the next couple of words, so the meaning depends on the context.